# Why did jupyter server fail in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I had this problem for a while now. I am trying to work on Jupyter Notebooks on VS code, but the jupyter server doesn't connect when I open VS code directly, but it works when I open VS code from Anaconda. Here is the error message:

```
Activating Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('base': conda) to run Jupyter failed with Error: StdErr from ShellExec, tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
 for . /Users/jingzhaogao/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python /Users/jingzhaogao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.88468/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py /Users/jingzhaogao/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.88468/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py.
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's nothing to specifically do here other than continue to open VS Code from the activated conda environment. Conda simply wants to own the environment you work from and those settings need to propagate into the one VS Code works from to make conda work.